# How can I join 3 SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, join

How can this 3 queries be joined into 1.

Im not lookin for an UNION ALL result.

**Per row I want Forecast, Budget, Actual**

```
SELECT 
    ps.PersonId, 
    SUM(TF.Hours * r.Amount) as Forecast
FROM ProjectStaffing ps
INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
INNER JOIN TimeForecast TF on (TF.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
GROUP BY ps.PersonId

SELECT 
    ps.PersonId, 
    SUM(tb.Hours * r.Amount) as Budget
FROM ProjectStaffing ps
INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
INNER JOIN TimeBudget tb on (tb.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
GROUP BY ps.PersonId

SELECT 
    ps.PersonId, 
    SUM(ta.Hours * r.Amount) as Actual
FROM ProjectStaffing ps
INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
INNER JOIN TimeActual ta on (ta.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
GROUP BY ps.PersonId
```

I tried this out but just gets strange results

```
SELECT 
    PS.PersonId, 
    SUM(TF.Hours * r.Amount) as Forecast,
    SUM(TB.Hours * r.Amount) as Budget,
    SUM(TA.Hours * r.Amount) as Actual
FROM ProjectStaffing PS
INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = PS.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = PS.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = PS.RoleId)
LEFT JOIN TimeForecast TF on (TF.ProjectStaffingId = PS.Id)
LEFT JOIN TimeBudget TB   on (TB.ProjectStaffingId = PS.Id)
LEFT JOIN TimeActual TA   on (TA.ProjectStaffingId = PS.Id)
WHERE PS.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    AND TF.Hours is not null
GROUP BY PS.PersonId
```

Comment: remove `and TF.Hours is not null` or replace it with `and (TF.Hours is not null or TB.Hours is not null or TA.Hours is not null)`

Comment: what do you mean strange result? can you just add the sample result to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this does the job. But it is too complex. There should be an easier way.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        --ps.PersonId, 
        'FORECAST' AS Description,
        SUM(TF.Hours * r.Amount) as Total --Forecast
    FROM ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN TimeForecast TF on (TF.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    --GROUP BY ps.PersonId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        --ps.PersonId, 
        'BUDGET' AS Description,
        SUM(tb.Hours * r.Amount) as Total --Budget
    FROM ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN TimeBudget tb on (tb.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    --GROUP BY ps.PersonId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        --ps.PersonId, 
        'ACTUAL' AS Description,
        SUM(ta.Hours * r.Amount) as Total --Actual
    FROM ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN Rate r on (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN TimeActual ta on (ta.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    --GROUP BY ps.PersonId
) p
PIVOT (SUM(p.Total) FOR [Description] in ([FORECAST], [BUDGET], [ACTUAL]) ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

One straight-forward way to do it is to use [`Common Table Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175972.aspx).

If all three subqueries have rows for each `PersonId`, then you can `INNER JOIN` them in any order. If one of the subqueries doesn't have rows for all `PersonIds`, then `LEFT JOIN` it.

```
WITH CTE_Forecast AS
(
    SELECT 
        ps.PersonId, 
        SUM(TF.Hours * r.Amount) as Forecast
    FROM 
        ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN 
        Rate r ON (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId 
                   AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId 
                   AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN 
        TimeForecast TF on (TF.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE 
        ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    GROUP BY 
        ps.PersonId
)
, CTE_Budget AS
(
    SELECT 
        ps.PersonId, 
        SUM(tb.Hours * r.Amount) as Budget
    FROM 
        ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN 
        Rate r ON (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId 
                   AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId 
                   AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN 
        TimeBudget tb on (tb.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE 
        ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    GROUP BY 
        ps.PersonId
)
, CTE_Actual AS
(
    SELECT 
        ps.PersonId, 
        SUM(ta.Hours * r.Amount) as Actual
    FROM 
        ProjectStaffing ps
    INNER JOIN 
        Rate r ON (r.ProviderId = ps.ProviderId 
                   AND r.OrganizationId = ps.OrganizationId 
                   AND r.RoleId = ps.RoleId)
    INNER JOIN 
        TimeActual ta on (ta.ProjectStaffingId = ps.Id)
    WHERE 
        ps.ProjectId = @ProjectId
    GROUP BY 
        ps.PersonId
)
SELECT
    CTE_Forecast.PersonId,
    CTE_Forecast.Forecast,
    CTE_Budget.Budget, 
    CTE_Actual.Actual
FROM
    CTE_Forecast
INNER JOIN 
    CTE_Budget ON CTE_Budget.PersonId = CTE_Forecast.PersonId
INNER JOIN 
    CTE_Actual ON CTE_Actual.PersonId = CTE_Forecast.PersonId
;
```